# Application of mean value theorem to $\int^{6\pi}_{4\pi} \frac{\sin x}{x}dx$ yields incorrect result

Tags: integration, analysis

I've come up with the following proof for $\int^{6\pi}_{4\pi} \frac{\sin x}{x}dx = 0$:

> The statement is true, due to the mean value theorem specifying the existence of a $k \in [2\pi,4\pi]$ such that:
>
> \begin{align*}
> \int^{6\pi}_{4\pi} \frac{\sin x}{x}dx 
> &= \frac{1}{k}\int^{6\pi}_{4\pi}\sin x dx \\
> &= \frac{1}{k}(- \cos x \bigg|^{6\pi}_{4\pi}) \\
> &= \frac{\cos 4\pi - \cos 6\pi}{k} \\
> &= 0 
> \end{align*}

However according to [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20(sin(x)%2Fx)%20from%204pi%20to%206pi) this does not seem to be correct. Is the mean value theorem not applicable here for some reason, or did I do something else wrong here?

Comment: You can't apply mean value theorem for definite integral here because $\sin x$ is neither non-negative nor non-positive over $[4\pi,6\pi]$.

Comment: I do not see how what you wrote relates to the mean value theorem. Could you please include the statement of the MVT, and how you apply it.

Comment: @Mirko I'm using the MVT $\int_a^b f(x) g(x) dx = f(c) \int_a^b  g(x) dx$ with $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ and $g(x) = \sin(x)$.

Comment: aah, well, but then @achillehui already observed that in this case $g$ need to have the same sign on $[a,b]$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#First_mean_value_theorem_for_definite_integrals

Comment: Oh yes... of cause. Thanks a lot! @achillehui could you please post your comment as answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One version of mean value theorem for definite integral states:

> Given two functions $f, g$ on $[ a, b ]$. If $f$ is continuous and $g$ is an integrable function which doesn't change sign on $[ a, b ]$, then there exists $c \in (a,b)$  such that
>   $$\int_a^b f(x) g(x) dx = f(c) \int_a^b g(x) dx$$

For your case, you can't apply this version of mean value theorem because
$g(x) = \sin x$ changes sign over $[4\pi, 6\pi]$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int\frac{\sin x}x\,dx$$
does *not* evaluate to $-\cos x+K$ because of the division by $x$. This is one of the trigonometric integrals and has its own notation:
$$\int\frac{\sin x}x\,dx=\operatorname{Si}(x)+K$$
Therefore your proof is wrong and
$$\int_{4\pi}^{6\pi}\frac{\sin x}x\,dx=\operatorname{Si}(6\pi)-\operatorname{Si}(4\pi)=0.02587\dots$$